# Errors with Saving/Loading C++ Data

Tags: c++, save, loading

So I'm developing this little resource gathering game in C++ here. Everything related to the game (that is developed) works perfectly... however, saving and loading progress seems to be quite the issue for me.

I've used a few different methods, and after giving up a little custom stuff (naming your save file) I got it to save. But now, when loaded, it seems to make the 'wood' variable have a large number, and things like stone, the name etc. are ignored.

Code:

- Saving

  ```
  ofstream saveFile;
  saveFile.open("save.save");
  saveFile << wood << stone << iron << gold << hasHatchet << hasPickaxe << hasDrill << hasPlasma_Cutter << hatchetLevel << pickaxeLevel << drillLevel << pcutterLevel << name;
  saveFile.close();
  ```
- Loading

  ```
  ifstream loadFile;
  loadFile.open("save.save");
  loadFile >> wood >> stone >> iron >> gold >> hasHatchet >> hasPickaxe >> hasDrill >> hasPlasma_Cutter >> hatchetLevel >> pickaxeLevel >> drillLevel >> pcutterLevel >> name;
  loadFile.close();
  goto mainProg;
  ```
- Variables (for reference)

  ```
  int wood = 0;
  int stone = 0;
  int iron = 0;
  int gold = 0; // Resource variables
  bool hasHatchet = true;
  bool hasPickaxe = false;
  bool hasDrill = false;
  bool hasPlasma_Cutter = false; // Tool boolean values
  int hatchetLevel = 1;
  int pickaxeLevel = 0;
  int drillLevel = 0;
  int pcutterLevel = 0; // Tool level variables
  string name = "";
  ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you save those variables without spaces, so save.save will contain string `000010001000`. When it is loaded, the program will recognize those string as wood, which make the wood variable have those large number

Try separating the variables with space while saving

`saveFile << wood << " " << stone << " " << iron << " " <<gold;`

Comment: @Matt watch out for `endl`. It is a line feed and a stream flush to the underlying media, a file in this case. This is an extremely expensive operation as you wind up writing to the file every time you add an item rather than buffering the data and only writing the buffer to the file when you need to. for ease of visually inspecting the file for debugging I'd recommend something similar to Arianto's suggestion: `saveFile << wood << " " << stone << " " << iron << " " <<gold << '\n';` the newline on the end visually separates one group from the next and doesn't force a flush.